# PowerBI, if contains 4 numbers in a row?

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I'm looking for something similar to this,

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Subject Short",
each if Text.Contains([Subject], "1234") then "4 in a row" 
each if Text.Contains([Subject], "9117") then "4 in a row" 
each if Text.Contains([Subject], "5136") then "4 in a row" 
else "Other")
```

However I'm looking for a way to say any 4 numbers in a row. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"Column1", "Subject"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Subject Short", each if 
    Text.Contains(
        Text.Combine(
            List.ReplaceMatchingItems(
                Text.ToList([Subject]), {
                    {"0","1"}, 
                    {"1","1"}, 
                    {"2","1"}, 
                    {"3","1"}, 
                    {"4","1"}, 
                    {"5","1"}, 
                    {"6","1"}, 
                    {"7","1"}, 
                    {"8","1"}, 
                    {"9","1"}}
            )
        ),"1111") then "4 in a row" else "")
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Subject Short", each if List.Count(List.Select(List.Transform({0..9999}, each Number.ToText( _, "0000")), (x) => Text.Contains([Subject], x)))>0 then "4 in row" else "Other")
```